# WP Template customizing

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i'm trying to change my  single-post template ,But i can't the `the_content` Function.
Where should it be ?

```
<div class="single-post-content clearfix">
<?php
    the_content(esc_html__('Read more!', 'voyager'));
    wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<div class="page-link">' . esc_html__('Pages', 'voyager') . ': ', 'after' => '</div>'));
?>
</div>
```

Update 1 the entire code

```html
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all single posts and attachments
 */

get_header();

$pf = get_post_format();

$voyager_single_post_sidebar_under = cstheme_option( 'single_post_sidebar_under' );
$single_post_sidebar = cstheme_option( 'single_post_sidebar' );
$single_post_sidebar_position = '';
if( $single_post_sidebar == 'left-sidebar' ) {
    $single_post_sidebar_position = 'pull-right';
}

/* ADD 1 view for this post */
$post_views = (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "post_views", true) > 0 ? get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "post_views", true) : "0");
update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "post_views", (int)$post_views + 1);

$single_post_featured_img = cstheme_option( 'single_post_featured_img' );

$featured_image_url = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id());
?>
        
        <div class="container">
            
            <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                
                <div id="blog-single-wrap" class="<?php echo 'format-' . $pf . ' featured_img_' . $single_post_featured_img ?> clearfix">
                    
                    <?php if( isset( $single_post_featured_img ) && $single_post_featured_img == 'fullwidth' ) { ?>
                        
                        <div class="single_post_header">
                            <div class="featured_img_bg" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $featured_image_url; ?>);"></div>
                            <div class="single_post_meta_category"><?php the_category(', '); ?></div>
                            <h2 class="single-post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                            <div class="single_post_header_bottom">
                                <div class="single_post_meta">
                                    <span class="post-meta-date"><?php the_time('M j, Y') ?></span>
                                    <span class="post_meta_views"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> <span><?php echo (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "post_views", true) > 0 ? get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "post_views", true) : "0"); ?></span></span>
                                    <span class="post-meta-likes"><?php echo cstheme_likes(); ?></span>
                                    <span class="post-meta-comments"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i><?php echo get_comments_number(get_the_ID()); ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <?php if ( $single_post_sidebar != 'no-sidebar' && $voyager_single_post_sidebar_under != 'next' && ( $pf != 'image' && $pf != 'standard' ) ) { ?>
                            <div class="post_format_content mb55 text-center">
                                <?php get_template_part( 'framework/post-format/post', get_post_format() ); ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                        
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        
                        <div class="single_post_header">
                            <div class="single_post_meta_category"><?php the_category(', '); ?></div>
                            <h2 class="single-post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                            <div class="row single_post_header_bottom">
                                <div class="col-md-4 text-left">
                                    <div class="single_post_meta_author"><?php echo esc_html__('posted by', 'voyager') ?> <a class="heading_font" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID')) ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_author_meta('display_name') ?></a></div>
                                </div>
                        
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="single_post_meta">
                                <span class="post-meta-date"><?php the_time('M j, Y') ?></span>
                                        <span class="post_meta_views"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> <span><?php echo (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "post_views", true) > 0 ? get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "post_views", true) : "0"); ?></span></span>
                                        <span class="post-meta-likes"><?php echo cstheme_likes(); ?></span>
                                        <span class="post-meta-comments"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i><?php echo get_comments_number(get_the_ID()); ?></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
                                    <?php if(cstheme_option('single_post_sharebox') != 0) { get_template_part( 'templates/blog/sharebox' ); } ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    
                        <?php if ( $voyager_single_post_sidebar_under != 'next' ) { ?>
                            
                            <div class="post_format_content mb55 text-center">
                                <?php get_template_part( 'framework/post-format/post', get_post_format() ); ?>
                            </div>
                            
                        <?php } ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                    
                    <?php if( $single_post_sidebar != 'no-sidebar' ) { ?>
                        
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-9 <?php echo $single_post_sidebar_position; ?>">
                
                        <?php } ?>
                                
                                <?php if( isset( $single_post_featured_img ) && ( $single_post_featured_img == 'fullwidth' ) && ( $pf != 'image' && $pf != 'standard' ) && $voyager_single_post_sidebar_under != 'under' ) { ?>
                                
                                    <div class="post_format_content mb55 text-center">
                                        <?php get_template_part( 'framework/post-format/post', $pf ); ?>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                <?php } else if ( $single_post_featured_img != 'fullwidth' && $voyager_single_post_sidebar_under != 'under' ) { ?>
                                    
                                    <div class="post_format_content mb55 text-center">
                                        <?php get_template_part( 'framework/post-format/post', get_post_format() ); ?>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                <?php } ?>
                                
                                <div class="single-post-content clearfix">
                                    
                                    <?php
                                        the_content(esc_html__('Read more!', 'voyager'));
                                        wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<div class="page-link">' . esc_html__('Pages', 'voyager') . ': ', 'after' => '</div>'));
                                    ?>
                                   
                                </div>
                                <div class="posts_nav_link"><?php posts_nav_link(); ?></div>
                                
                                <div class="single_sharebox_wrap clearfix">
                                    <div class="single_post_meta_tags pull-left">
                                        
                                        <?php if( has_tag() ) {
                                            the_tags('','', '');
                                        } ?>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="pull-right">
                                        
                                        <?php if(cstheme_option('single_post_sharebox') != 0) { get_template_part( 'templates/blog/sharebox' ); } ?>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                
                                <?php if(cstheme_option('single_post_authorinfo') != 0) { get_template_part( 'templates/blog/authorinfo' ); } ?>
                                
                                <?php if(cstheme_option('single_post_navigation') != 0) { ?>
                                    <div class="single_post_nav clearfix">
                                        <?php
                                            $prev_post = get_adjacent_post(false, '', true);
                                            $next_post = get_adjacent_post(false, '', false);

                                            if($prev_post){
                                                $post_url = get_permalink($prev_post->ID);            
                                                echo '<div class="pull-left"><a href="' . esc_url( $post_url ) . '" title="' . $prev_post->post_title . '"><p class="heading_font"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>' . esc_html__('Previous','voyager') . '</p><b>' . $prev_post->post_title . '</b></a></div>';
                                            }

                                            if($next_post) {
                                                $post_url = get_permalink($next_post->ID);            
                                                echo '<div class="pull-right text-right"><a href="' . esc_url( $post_url ) . '" title="' . $next_post->post_title . '"><p class="heading_font">' . esc_html__('Next','voyager') . '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></p><b>' . $next_post->post_title . '</b></a></div>';
                                            } 
                                        ?>
                                    </div>
                                <?php } ?>
                    
                    <?php if( $single_post_sidebar != 'no-sidebar' ) { ?>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                    
                    <?php if(cstheme_option('single_post_relatedposts') != 0) { get_template_part('templates/blog/related-posts'); } ?>
                    
                    <?php 
                        if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                            comments_template();
                        endif;
                    ?>
                    
                </div>
                
            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
            
        </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The page is [enter link description here](https://primocamminodisantiago.com/2018/02/25/roncisvalle/)

Comment: what is your problem?Please explain?

Comment: This function is including the post content and the share buttons , I need to  add another function before the share buttons

Comment: Please post your full code?on this code there is no share button.

Comment: yeah that's is  wait i will show you the entire code